# Get data from windows.onload event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, url

I have a onload function to split a data from the current URL.

```
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.name;
}
```

**I need to use the split value from windows.onload event to a function**

```
    var te='https://myurl.html?AID=' + data; //need to use the split value here
```

Comment: Please elaborate, right now it's not quite clear what you're trying to do

Comment: I have a url with a data i need to use it on the current html. I used onclick function from a form to move the input value from that form to the other html through URL like

`onclick= location.href = 'url.html?AID=' +value"`

This opens the url with the value. I need to use this value on that specific file using windows onload function. I'm not sure how to do it. 

I'm not a professional coder. Pardon me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
const url = new URL(document.location.href);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // page load
  document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = url.searchParams.get('name'); // gets the &name=whatever
  const te = `https://myurl.html?AID=${url.searchParams.get('AID')}`; // gets the AID=whatever
})
```